# Correct way to parse json in python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2, urllib3

I was given a task to read json from a url and then parse it in python. Each field will be assigned to a variable to store the value. The value will then be stored into postgres table.

**Example of Json**

```
{
 "forecasts": 
[
 {
   "class": "fod_long_range_daily",
   "expire_time_gmt": 1525126617,
   "night": {
     "fcst_valid": 1525158000,
     "fcst_valid_local": "2018-05-01T19:00:00+1200",
     "golf_category": ""
   },
   "day": {
     "uv_warning": 0,
     "uv_desc": "Moderate",
     "golf_index": 10,
     "golf_category": "Excellent"
   }
 }
]
}
```

I was told that this way i am able to parse json and read it into postgres. Can i know if I am doing the right way? Will there be performance issue ?

**Style 1:**

```
import urllib3
import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="nzaus", 
user="admin", password="123321")
print("Database Connected")
cur = conn.cursor()
rowcount = cur.rowcount

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "https://api.data.com/v1/geocode/-35.228208/174.095969/forecast/daily/15day.json?language=en-US&units=m&apiKey=1234"
try:
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    data = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))

    for item in data['forecasts']:
        class = None
        time = None
        fcst_valid = None
        golf_category = None

        result = []

        class = item['class']
        time  = item['expire_time_gmt']
        fcst_valid = item['night']['fcst_valid']
        golf_category = item['morning']['golf_category']
        result = [class,time,fcst_valid,golf_category]

        cur.execute("""INSERT into datatable 
                       VALUES
                       ( %s,
                         %s,
                         %s,
                         %s,
                       )""",(result))
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
 except IOError as io:
    print("cannot open")
```

Comment: If this code works it's off-topic here. You might have more luck on [codereview.se]. Make sure to take their tour to make sure you're following their rules.

Comment: For questions about code, StackOverflow's scope is limited to asking about specific problems, and does not extend to review for general comment or suggestion. See [A Guide to Code Review for StackOverflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for guidance on which questions are appropriate on each site (if either).

Comment: ...that said -- at a glance, the biggest thing that sticks out as a sore thumb to me is the shadowing of the keyword `class`. Sure, you *could* pass the plaintext into PostgreSQL and let the initial parse to JSON happen there, but assuming your datatypes are JSON or JSONB (and that your documents really are small, as in the example), it should work out either way -- and the performance advantage of avoiding the extra parse/generate cycle needs to be weighed against getting potentially harder-to-process error messages.

Comment: ...actually, doing a whole separate commit (and closing your cursor?!) for each item is a much bigger concern. If you care about efficiency, you should be doing larger transactions -- and certainly keep your cursor open.